# SSRS select random records in tablix filter , possible

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I need to insert extra tab into existing report and display only @ratio percent of records randomly, so trying to solve this inside the tablix filter, is it possible, I don't think there is place for SQL in expression builder. I can include NewID() in original DataSet too like in case#1 below, but I prefer solve it without it, so it will be completely isolated change.  This is just some methods I know in SQL for all reference. I also attaching test rdl for test. Tx all.M

```
SELECT TOP 40 PERCENT * FROM  #TABLE  ORDER BY NEWID()  -- case #1

SELECT TOP 40 PERCENT * FROM  #TABLE                    -- case #2
WHERE (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM (Report_Type+Name, NEWID())) as int))  % 100) < @rate
```

#### Tablix filter

[image: Tablix filter image here]

Sorry, can not attach my rdl so pasating its xml right her, just plug your dsource, tx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>Test random records     Rate = </Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>14pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>=Parameters!Ratio.Value</Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>14pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Height>0.45833in</Height>
        <Width>6.63542in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.27083in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>0.98958in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox2">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>#1 ALL rows</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Priority</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox6">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Name</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Report_Type">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Report_Type.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Report_Type</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Priority">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Priority.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Priority</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Name">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Name.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Name</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Details" />
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Top>0.655in</Top>
        <Height>0.5in</Height>
        <Width>3.26042in</Width>
        <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix2">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.35417in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.41667in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>#2 Sample</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>Khaki</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox5">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Priority</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>Khaki</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox7">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Name</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>Khaki</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Report_Type2">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Report_Type.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Report_Type</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Priority2">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Priority.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Priority</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Name2">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!Name.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Name</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Details2" />
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Top>0.655in</Top>
        <Left>4.04166in</Left>
        <Height>0.5in</Height>
        <Width>3.77084in</Width>
        <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>3.06597in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>8.10417in</Width>
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>DataSource_Test</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>ba5e4bce-4b57-4614-bf51-765e4c1d08fc</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT        'Report A' AS Report_Type, 'Cat100' AS Priority, 'John' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report B' AS Report_Type, 'Cat100' AS Priority, 'Mary B' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report B' AS Report_Type, 'Cat100' AS Priority, 'Mary BB' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report B' AS Report_Type, 'Cat200' AS Priority, 'Kent B' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report CC' AS Report_Type, 'Cat100' AS Priority, 'Linda C' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report CC' AS Report_Type, 'Cat200' AS Priority, 'Joh  C' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report CC' AS Report_Type, 'Cat300' AS Priority, 'Ben CC1' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report CC' AS Report_Type, 'Cat300' AS Priority, 'Ben CC2' AS Name
UNION
SELECT        'Report CC' AS Report_Type, 'Cat300' AS Priority, 'Ben CC3' AS Name</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Report_Type">
          <DataField>Report_Type</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Priority">
          <DataField>Priority</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Name">
          <DataField>Name</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="Ratio">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>20</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>Sample Ratio (%)</Prompt>
      <ValidValues>
        <ParameterValues>
          <ParameterValue>
            <Value>1</Value>
            <Label>1</Label>
          </ParameterValue>
          <ParameterValue>
            <Value>10</Value>
            <Label>10</Label>
          </ParameterValue>
          <ParameterValue>
            <Value>20</Value>
            <Label>20</Label>
          </ParameterValue>
          <ParameterValue>
            <Value>30</Value>
            <Label>30</Label>
          </ParameterValue>
          <ParameterValue>
            <Value>40</Value>
            <Label>40</Label>
          </ParameterValue>
        </ParameterValues>
      </ValidValues>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="Dummy">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Run Report</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>7cd57505-e020-4554-a48c-99f2725fc948</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Comment: Do you want to select the top x% of records, using a parameter?

Comment: Tx Abuguid,   Yes 10% (or variable like in @Rate paramter), No - they should be random, not top by some key or some internal rowID. I can use option #1 generating random NewID() and sort by them. Maybe some other ways do this.

Comment: With TOP N, is it possible to do some calc in expression to get %?

Comment: I tried to use this expression in Filter for top N:  like below, but got error < can not used aggregation in filter>  DataRows() is aggregation

Comment: =Round((Parameters!Ratio.Value /100 ) * CountRows("DataSet1"),0)

Comment: Also tried ReportElement with calculated N, also says can not use it in Filter Expression.  How to add this dynamics into top N ??

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're after. You can calculate the percent within the query.

```
DECLARE @ratio AS DECIMAL
SET @ratio = 30 -- your percent parameter here

;WITH
test_data
AS
(
    SELECT [row_count_nbr] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Name]), tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'name1', 123)
    , ( 'name2', 234)
    , ( 'name3', 1234)
    , ( 'name4', 56)
    , ( 'name5', 4)
    , ( 'name6', 34)
    , ( 'name7', 784)
    ) tbl ([Name], [Value]) 
)
, 
test_data_row_percent
AS
(
SELECT 
      [Name]
    , [Value]
    , [row_count_nbr]
    , [percent_of_rows] = CAST(([row_count_nbr] * 100) AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)) AS DECIMAL)
FROM 
    test_data
)
SELECT * FROM test_data_row_percent WHERE [percent_of_rows] <= @ratio
```

#### Results with filter

[image: filter results]

#### Results without filter

[image: unfiltered results]

Comment: Thanks much Aduguid,  yes I think this can be done only in DataSet production step in SQL, none of my attempts worked in SSRS filters

Comment: You may be interested in my reporting services examples in GitHub. https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples